# Filter .txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text-files

First of all here is the output of my file:

```
   License Administration Tool Version 6.418.1 Built on 16.10.2015 15:03:18.
admin >connect ch-s-0001504 4084
    Software version: 6.216.0
    Build date: 29.10.2013 15:21:54
    Standalone mode
    Ready: yes
    Server name: ch-s-0001504   Server id: FYT-42B8101A64CAD992
Warning: restricted connection, some operations are not permitted; due to an existing connection in full access from CH-W-7000357.ch.abb.com/10.41.33.65
admin >getLicenseUsage -feature DL1
    Dassault Systemes V5 (B42B3C3E-8CA2-422F-8B69-89556C54D4FC)
        DL1  maxReleaseNumber: 0  maxReleaseDate: 01.02.18 00:59:00 type: ConcurrentUser  count: 1  inuse: 0 customerId: 200000000009118
admin >
```

What I am trying to do is to filter through this whole file for the values of count and inuse as well as the first 3 letters after "Dassault Systemes V5" here DL1

what I did so far:

```bash
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledeylayedexpansion
for /f "token=1,3"%%a in ('type all.txt') do(
    if "x%%a" == "xcount"(
    echo %%a %%b
    )
    if "x%%a"=="xinuse"(
    echo %%a %%b
    )
)
endlocal
```

I just don't know if that is even the right approach or not?

Comment: if you don't use any `!` variables inside your loops, delayed expansion isn't needed, look [here](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq skip=10 tokens=1,10,12 delims= " %%a in ("all.txt") do (
    set "feature=%%a"
    set "count=%%b"
    set "inuse=%%c"
    goto :breakloop
)
:breakloop
echo count: %count%
echo inuse: %inuse%
echo feature: %feature%
pause
```

in `for /f` loops, if you use skip you can skip a certain amount of lines, and you can break loops using a goto (even if the label is inside a loop, so don't do that). as your feature, count and inuse variables are the 1st, 10th and 12th token, we use `tokens=1,10,12` to set them as `%%a`, `%%b` and `%%c`. I use `usebackq` so I can notify the loop that the value in parenthesis is a file that should be read, while still being able to use double quotes, for if the filename contains a space.

**EDIT**

Version to get multiple counts/inuses/features:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,9,10,11,12 delims= " %%a in ("all.txt") do (
    if "%%b"=="count:" if "%%d"=="inuse:" (
        set "feature=%%a"
        set "count=%%c"
        set "inuse=%%e"
        echo count: !count!
        echo inuse: !inuse!
        echo feature: !feature!
        echo.
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Oh man thanks allot for your answer ! is there a chance how to get those 3 letters in the beginning ? "DL1" ? and write the result into a different text file ?

Comment: @NikoKing if your file is the text in the question, the line you're parsing starts with `DS1`, and that is the first token, so it should have that value, and it did in my tests. Are you sure the content of the file matches the text in your question (**newlines included**)

Comment: @NikoKing in that case I suspect you added a newline to the top of the file, which causes the skip to not skip far enough

Comment: @NikoKing seeing as you accepted my answer, I'm guessing the problem is solved? For future reference, would you mind telling me what it was?

Comment: btw just a quick followup for example if my file would have multiple count values and inuse etc this script would only get the top is that right , and if so is there a quick way to get all  ?

Comment: @NikoKing edited, btw, now you **do** need delayed expansion